# GPA calculation in German Grading system

Tags: university, grades, germany, grading, gpa

I am studying in a German University where the GPA grades are : 
1.0 , 1.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.7, 4.0 with 1.0 being the best score a student can get in exam and below 4.0 it is fail.

However, My score card looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, graded average = 204.6/108 = 1.89 and my actual result in the scorecard is 2.2. (I also have seen the related questions for this in forum and they don't answe my question.)

Could anyone please explain the calculation behind this ?

Comment: Check what the actual computation method is. From my German _Bauchgefühl_ I'd say that you should average _grades_, but there are definitely special rules. For example, the thesis is often factored-in twice, thus it has a larger weight.

Comment: It is very likely that not all your classes contribute to your GPA. The only studies I know use either 90, 120 or 180 credits as the final score. You have to fulfill certain conditions and the best combination of grades that fulfills all conditions gives your GPA. What theses conditions are you need to check with your university (for example in this case I would assume you cannot have "project II" twice).

Comment: Is this a typo that Project II occurs twice? If not, this might explain it. Normally you can pass each module only once, so the system might not take a second try into account. Ignoring the 1.0 in Project II and only taking the 2.7 into account, you end up with 174.6/78=2.2 (rounded).

Comment: Yes. That would be project I and project II

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess your subjects are part of modules?
Then you need to calculate and round every module on itself and afterwards you can calculate your GPA based on the modules.

Have you checked your *Prüfungsordnung* (examination regulations)?
In it the calculation method of your GPA is stated.

If the GPA is still unclear after checking the document, you should contact your Examination Office.
Maybe they have a system/display bug and/or some "buffer marks" (have you something like 18 credits open, i.e. registered, but not taken yet, then grading it with 4.0 in the system would yield a grade of 2.2) or something that cannot be checked or verified from outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) . I have attache the image a little wrong. I am going to correct them. The grades I mentioned there are Module (One module has 2 subjects).

Comment: I didn't see Prüfungsordnung.

Comment: I couldn't find one.

Comment: You _have_ a Prüfungsordnung. For sure.

Comment: @SrijaniGhosh Oleg is correct. If you are at a German university, then you will have a Prüfungsordnung.